# Error in loop: Attempted to access L(1); index out of bounds because numel(L)=0

Tags: matlab

I tried searching, but don't seem to see any solutions for my problem. It says

> Attempted to access L(1); index out of bounds because
>   numel(L)=0.
>
> Error in Energy_Management_code (line 64)
>   a(k)=L(1);

and this is the code that got error

```
%Arranging the data according to its location
L=NUMERIC(:,Location_no_column);
k=1;
a(k)=L(1);
p(1).loc=find(L/a(k)==1);
L(p(1).loc)=nan;

while max(isfinite(L))==1
   next=min(FIND(isfinite(L)));
   a(length(a)+1)=L(next);
   p(length(a)).loc=find(L/a(length(a))==1);
   L(p(length(a)).loc)=nan;
end

for i=1:length(a)
   Location(i).ID=a(i);
   Location(i).Place=p(i).loc;
   Location(i).Number=length(Location(i).Place);
end
```

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I can see, the error is very simple.

```
a(k) = L(1);
```

This line errors out because `numel(L)=0`, which means L is empty. I'm guessing the line creates an empty L.

```
L = NUMERIC(:,Location_no_column);
```

Check what `NUMERIC(:,Location_no_column)` prints out and confirm.